# Multi-Line TextField in Flutter*

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text field with a limited width. I want it to automatically move to the next line when one line is filled. After that, I want to count the number of lines. I am currently using the following method:

```
String textLine =
    homeController
        .textFieldController
        .text
        .split('\n')[index];
```

However, I must press "Enter" for a new line to be recognized; otherwise, it goes to the next line but does not count it.

Something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
auto_size_text_field: ^2.2.2
```

---

```
AutoSizeTextField(
  controller: _textEditingController,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 2,
)
```

---

Set `maxLines` based on your screen

Answer (score 0):

I think [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) is what you are looking for.